# Django - ImageField save to user folder fails

Tags: django

I can successfully upload a file but I can not state the folder as the logged in username.  I have tried the following:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    document = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

but receive the following error:

```
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value: Document has no user.
```

The form is as follows:

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('document', )
```

With the view as follows:

```
@login_required
def profile(request, extra_context={}):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'meta/profile.html', {
                  'form': form
                  })
```

Any advice would be appreciated, Alan.

Full trace below:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/

Django Version: 1.9.6
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'avatar',
 'mathfilters',
 'smart_selects',
 'tinymce',
 'dbbackup',
 'django_ical',
 'crispy_forms',
 'meta')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'fbf.middleware.QueryCountDebugMiddleware')



Traceback:

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
      23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/alantingey/freebetfriend.com/meta/views.py" in profile
      71.             form.save()

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in save
      451.             self.instance.save()

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
      708.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
      736.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
      820.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
      859.                                using=using, raw=raw)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
      122.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
      1039.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
      1059.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
      1019.                 for obj in self.query.objs

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in pre_save_val
      968.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
      311.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
      90.         name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)

    File "/Users/alantingey/virtualenv/fbf/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in generate_filename
      328.             directory_name, filename = os.path.split(self.upload_to(instance, filename))

    File "/Users/alantingey/freebetfriend.com/meta/models.py" in user_directory_path
      22.     today_date = datetime.datetime.today().date()

    Exception Type: AttributeError at /profile/
    Exception Value: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: Can you add the complete error traceback? Most probably your Document object's user is set to None.

Comment: Am currently at a pantomime lol. Will add the moment I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not collecting the logged in user anywhere! Your form only collects the document field.

```
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = ('document', )
```

So it's natural that the following code would fail

```
return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)
```

To fix it change your view to

```
obj = form.save(commit=False)
obj.user = request.user
obj.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly.  The only issue is if the filename exists and they try to upload again it causes the following error: "Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
(1062, "Duplicate entry '18' for key 'user_id'")".  But if not obvious I am happy to fix it shortly :)

Comment: Can't say for sure since you haven't posted the models but i think you probably might need ForeignKey instead of OneToOneField

Comment: I realised that almost straight after going back to it :P . Many thanks sir.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have

```
from datetime import datetime
```

so either your command should be

```
today_date = datetime.today().date()
```

or just update your `import` statement to

```
import datetime
```

Comment: Sorry sir, I think my traceback ended up being linked to a different problem as I was mid fixing something.  You solved my next problem.  Thank you.